# Read multiple datasets from a single file - pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a fixed width file which looks like this:

```
H10001234567ABC
D123......
D124......
D125......
T10000003
H10001234567DEF
D234......
D235......
D236......
T10000003
```

The first line starting with H is the header which corresponds to the first data set followed by detail data and then a trailer record with number of detail records. A single file can have more than one such grouping. My objective is to load header, detail and trailer records separately into 3 different dataframes and I should have a common key tying them together like this:

```
Header DF:

Key | Attribute1 | Attribute2 | Attribute3
1   | H1000      | 1234567    | ABC
2   | H1000      | 1234567    | DEF

Detail DF:

Key | Attribute1 | ....
1   | 123        | ....
1   | 124        | ....
1   | 125        | ....
2   | 234        | ....
2   | 235        | ....
2   | 236        | ....

Trailer DF:

Key | Attribute1 | Count
1   | 1000       | 3
2   | 1000       | 3
```

Best way on how this can be done? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using the following solution, you can separate records into 3 dataframes, then you can separate data strings into columns using `substring`([link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.substring.html)) transformation.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

input_df = spark.read.text('<path_to_input_file>')

header_df = (
    input_df
    .where(f.col('value').rlike('^H.*$'))
)

detail_df = (
    input_df
    .where(f.col('value').rlike('^D.*$'))
)

trailer_df = (
    input_df
    .where(f.col('value').rlike('^T.*$'))
)
```